# Azure VNet integration inconsistent between instances

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created two identical resource groups (other than their names) that contain some key vaults and a storage account and I want to add an app service (and plan) to each resource group and connect them to a VNet in a third separate resource group (all within the US West region).

The problem is, the app service in ResourceGroup1, when I go to Networking --> VNet Integration --> Click here to configure shows me this when I click "+ Add VNet" [image: Not what I want!]

But the in ResourceGroup2, when I add an app service and go to Networking --> VNet Integration --> Click here to configure, it shows me this when I click "+ Add VNet"[image: What I want each time.]

I want to utilize the "Same region" VNet integration on both App Services in both Resource Groups, and they are all exact copies with just the names different. So why do this setup differ from one to the other and how can I *always* get the second option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can scale up your App Service plan to a **PremiumV2** tier in your ResourceGroup1 or make sure that you are using **an App Service Plan where the PremiumV2 option is available**, refer to [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration).

> The feature is available only from **newer Azure App Service scale units
> that support PremiumV2 App Service plans**. Note that this does not mean
> your app must run on a PremiumV2 pricing tier, only that it must run
> on an App Service Plan where the PremiumV2 option is available (which
> implies that it is a newer scale unit where this VNet integration
> feature is then also available).

For more information, you could look at this [useful answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/91026/view.html).

> Even though the documentation above claims this feature is supported
> on the Standard tier, it's a hit or miss depending on what scale unit
> you're provisioned on. The only reliable way to get this accomplished
> is by provisioning a PremiumV2 tier.